# Would you like to have the accepted answer pinned or unpinned on UNIX & Linux?

Tags: discussion, answers, user-interface, accepted-answer

I've just been made aware of [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) where it says:

> Currently we are planning to move forward with one of two scenarios,
> based on your feedback:
>
> - Unpin the accepted answer on all SE sites by default and pin it back on a few sites that ask us to do so.
> - Keep the accepted answer pinned on all SE sites by default and unpin it on a few sites that ask us to do so.

Please visit the linked post to voice your thoughts. Feedback on that post is requested by the end of September 19th.

Leave an answer here if you'd like to see accepted answers pinned or unpinned for U&L.

Comment: I agree with Faheem. For readers who don’t, assuming answers are unpinned, they can get the old behaviour back with [Glorfindel’s userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/285232).

Comment: My highest-voted answer on the site wasn't accepted, though it got me a populist badge for (initially) outscoring by far the answer that ended up being accepted.  I suppose I've missed out on a lot of votes since then because of the pinning.  Should I recuse myself from this poll?  ;)  :D

Comment: I've locked the two existing answers as the voting period has closed for this round.

Answer (score 29):

I think it would be best to have accepted answers unpinned on U&L. I see no reason to treat accepted answers specially.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest that unpinning is the better behaviour. Two situations come to mind:

When a question is answered by a quick&dirty solution, that may work for the OP, and may therefore be accepted. If a more robust, less error prone or just more elegant solution is posted later, that will (probably) be upvoted, pushing the inferior, but accepted, solution downward.

Also, things change a bit. For example, an answer on how to configure networks on Ubuntu may have a pre-systemd answer as accepted. If a new, systemd-compliant answer is given, that could be up-voted to replace the accepted, but obsolete, answer at the top.