# Why is there a delay to accept one's own answer to one's own question?

Tags: discussion, support

Just surprised today regarding [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718026/lprm-cancel-both-fail-to-cancel-print-jobs) for which I found and just posted an answer.

Since the answer perfectly & logically… answers my question, I tried to accept it (in order for the community not to bother any longer with the question) and was rejected, told to wait for tomorrow. (the same delay I would have faced for offering a bounty)

Why is this latency enforced ? (why are these latencies (including the delay for offering a bounty) enforced ?)

Answer (score 3):

Accepting an answer essentially means "Yes, this is the solution I was looking for". I believe the thinking here is that since this is your question, you should give others the chance to answer before accepting because some people may see an accepted answer and then not bother answering with their own solution.

This is hinted at in the Help Center page about [self answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

The bounty delay is different. I think the idea there is to avoid spamming the system by bountying a question before it's had a chance to work its way through the regular process of people seeing it and answering it. Not 100% sure about this one.

Comment: I'd rather say than accepting an answer means "This is the solution **I'm happy with**". Incidentally implying that I personally switched to something else and (wouldn't it be for the sole sake of politeness) would not even read other answers. That question no longer presents any interest to myself => community is welcomed to consider identically. No need to wait for that. Adding that… I'm not used to get more than one single answer to my questions… (If any)

Comment: @MC68020 if you're really done with that question, why even bother accepting any answer?

Comment: @muru : That is precisely my very point against the delay : I will bother for the sole sake of politeness marking the question resolved-fixed as long as I stay on that page. That is for a short time after saving the edit of my answer. One ? Two days after… for sure… I won't bother…  for having my mind of whatever else.

Comment: @MC68020 that's OK. II think the idea is we'd rather have more answers than one, accepted one.

Comment: @MC68020 I suspect that one factor is that questions with an accepted answer get much less attention in general — at least, I’ve noticed that answers that are accepted quickly tend to attract fewer views and votes than questions that spend a little while unaccepted. So an self-answered Q with a quickly-accepted answer would be less likely to get a better answer (if there is one).

Comment: @StephenKitt : You are correct ! (As usual) I do not, myself, click on questions having an accepted answer. (That is why I find this acceptance useful since it saves time to the community). Of course, when I ask some question, what I am looking for is an answer, not earning credit. So, yes indeed, accepting an answer will lead to less views (adding the fact that the question won't give food to the sombre *community user* ;-) ) hence less possible upvotes. But… as far as I get an answer I'm happy with… who cares ?

Comment: Not to say that I already answered two of my own questions with a solution I was not that much happy with, did not consequently accept the answers. No other answer went posted, credit on the question has not increased and number of views is not **much** different compared to those for which I accepted the answer. OK, I acknowledge, this is not worth more than my personal experience.

Comment: @MC68020 but why even bother marking it as solved?

Comment: @muru : < kidding > Clever ! You actually found the ultimate way to force me accepting terdon's answer :-) < /kidding > Well… if your last comment gets the same meaning than the #2 then my #3 comment stands as my answer. :-P

Comment: If it were up to me, I would remove the "accept" functionality entirely. It often doesn't mark the best answer and often just leads to drama and "waaah, why you no accept?" complaints. It's not worth the complications, IMO. Note how we have already stopped pinning the accepted answer to the top:[Would you like to have the accepted answer pinned or unpinned on UNIX & Linux?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5835)

Comment: < kidding > OK then, I now understand how to proceed. 1/ I vote for you as U&LSE dictator-in-chief 2/ I change this discussion into a feature request 3/ I come back whining "waaah, why don't you accept it ! </ kidding> Ha! was going to forget :  <kidding> Yes I do note how you work for the rich (those questions that get > 2 answers) < /kidding >

Comment: < kidding as Michael Palin in "Holy Grail"> "Is there anybody else we could talk to ?" </kidding>

Comment: Heh, I'm sure there is a feature request on MSE for this. Somewhere.